# Regex to identify characters in keyword

Tags: perl

I want to examine 1 or more characters that constitute a keyword.

So if the the keyword is "show", then s, sh, sho, or show all qualify but all other combinations would fail.

I'm thinking look-ahead is the solution but unsure how to make them optional and still enforce the requirement.

As in..

echo "s" | perl -ne 'print if /s(?=h)?(?=o)?(?=w)?/' should print

echo "sh" | perl -ne 'print if /s(?=h)?(?=o)?(?=w)?/' should print

echo "sho" | perl -ne 'print if /s(?=h)?(?=o)?(?=w)?/' should print

echo "show" | perl -ne 'print if /s(?=h)?(?=o)?(?=w)?/' should print

and

echo "st" | perl -ne 'print if /s(?=h)?(?=o)?(?=w)?/' should fail

echo "sto" | perl -ne 'print if /s(?=h)?(?=o)?(?=w)?/' should fail

echo "stop" | perl -ne 'print if /s(?=h)?(?=o)?(?=w)?/' should fail

etc.

Comment: What about this `/^(?:show|sho|sh|s)$/gm`, https://regex101.com/r/kV4PGr/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`index`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index) rather than a regex:

```
perl -nle 'print if index("show", $_) == 0'
```

(`-l` removes the newline from `$_` and adds one after `print`)

This one-liner will print the input if it's a prefix of `show` (ie, if the input is a substring of `show` that starts at index `0`).

---

If you really need a regex, I would suggest:

```
/^s(h(ow?)?)?$/
```

(use `(?:` instead of the `(` if performance of capture groups matter: it's basically the same thing except that it doesn't capture the group)

This kind of regex should be fairly easy to build programmatically with a recursive function:

```
sub build_re {
  my ($first, $end) = split //, $_[0], 2;
  return $first if $end eq "";
  return "$first(" . build_re($end) . ")?";
}

my $re = build_re("show");  # prints s(h(o(w)?)?)?

print "s" =~ /^$re$/ ? 1 : 0; # 1
print "sh" =~ /^$re$/ ? 1 : 0; # 1
print "show" =~ /^$re$/ ? 1 : 0; # 1

print "showw" =~ /^$re$/ ? 1 : 0; # 0
print "how" =~ /^$re$/ ? 1 : 0; # 0
```

The 3rd argument of [`split`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split) (`2`) tells `split` to only split in 2 fields rather than "as many as possible" (the default). This way, this `split` splits the input of `build_re` into "1st character" and "the rest". It's somewhat equivalent to `my ($first, $end) = $_[0] =~ /^(.)(.*)$/` (assuming that the input is on a single line).

Comment: The function build_re without recursion: sub build_re {my $a; for (reverse split(//,$_[0])) {$a = $a ? "$_($a)?" : $_} return $a; }

Answer (score 2):

Reverse think it. Use

```
'show' =~ m{^$keyword$}
```